# Two domains on same WP site, but different header

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress for a client's website and this client asked me if he could have two domains with the same content, but a different logo on top of the page. So for example:

www.website1.com with logo1
www.website2.com with logo2
Both with same theme & contents.

I was thinking of a double WP install, but then you have to do every change two times. I read something about multisites in Wordpress, but could not find out how to do this.
I hope someone can help me out, thanks!

Comment: one the SEO front this is a bad idea, you will duplicate all content Google won't know what to value more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the SEO front this is a bad idea, you will duplicate all content Google won't know what to value more. But if you really want it.

**you could do this with two wp install's but there are problems.**
First set your site url's in the [wp-config](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL)

- Second let both installs connect to the same database. The change in
- header can be detected with $_REQUEST (google it)

**Now there are 2 problems left which I don't know how to fix.**

- The uploads folder need to be synchronized so each site can access the uploads
  the solution will be with simlinks stuff. (which I'm not familiar with)
  And your hosting provider has to allow it.
- If you add an internal link in your post/pages it will prepend the complete site url, and save this hard coded in the database.
  The solution of this could be in the editor, of to filter the content before it is printed.

If you want to go this way I'm willing to look further into these problems

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just stay with a simple redirect. SEO is important for me. Maybe I can show website1.com under domain website2.com with some DNS changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [relatively recent article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/07/07/the-ultimate-wordpress-multi-site-network-management-guide/) on how to set a multisite wordpress network up.